# how to get array sizes in object react-native

Tags: react-native

*I used json.groupby on Json and it gives me arrays in object. But I dont know how to get that first array's lenght, second array's lenght ?*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map your keys of json object. So you can achieve each array.

```
let firstArrayLenght = 0;
let secondArrayLenght = 0;
Object.keys(yourJSON).map((key, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
        firstArrayLenght = yourJSON[key].length;
    } else if (index === 1) {
        secondArrayLenght = yourJSON[key].length;
    }

});
```

If you want all length of arrays, you can use;

```
let lengthsOfAllArray = [];
Object.keys(yourJSON).map((key, index) => {
    lengthsOfAllArray.push(yourJSON[key].lenght);
});
```

or you can push as an object key value pair. So you can read which array has which lenght.

```
Object.keys(yourJSON).map((key, index) => {
    let item = {
        key,
        lenght: yourJSON[key].lenght
    };
    lengthsOfAllArray.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Oh it works bro. But if we dont know how many array 
there are  in object ,how can we get all sizes ?

Comment: You are welcome @hakan. I add new approach for your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all sizes regarding the array length you can store its values on other array

```
let arrayLenghts = [];
Object.keys(jsonObj).map((key, index) => {
    arrayLenghts[index] = jsonObj[key].length;
});
```

Then you can search on `arrayLengths` the size of all arrays inside your JSON object